# What is the best way to get the latest version of R?

Tags: software-installation, r, rstudio

A lot of instructions that I find on here give instructions about how to install the latest version of R that either deliver an out of date version, or are very OS-dependent.  I just bought a System76 computer using Pop_OS so I'm not sure which OS-contingent installation instructions I could adapt to my situation.

As I understanding just using the package manager, `sudo apt-get install r-base` delivers an out of date version that cannot install the `ggplot2` package, so I can't solve my problem that way.

If I try to download from the main R site [here](https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-3/), it has a configure and make file, but it requires a ton of dependencies and I struggle to know how to get them all.  I've already chased down three dependencies but now on X11 I don't know how to get it.  I'll start chasing that down in a minute, but with all of this "extracurricular" work, I'm wondering if maybe there is a better way to install this software.  Is there something I can do to just ... install all relevant packages?  Or is there something else I can download to try to install R in some other way, and yet still get the latest version?

Comment: Ok, the reason you are not getting much help, here, I think, is because we have trouble identifying the version of Pop! OS you are using, the version of R that you have installed and the version of ggplot2 you want. From what I see, System76 comes with Pop! OS 19.10, which should have R version 3.5.2 and https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/all/r-cran-ggplot2/download wants 3.5.1 or higher.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at anaconda. I believe this would be very close to what you are looking

https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/

https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/using-r-language/